# Using C# to access D&B Direct webservice(WSDL) 101

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, wsdl

Trying to use the [Dun & Bradstreet webservice](https://docs.dnb.com/direct/2.0/en-US/quick-soap-API) and haven't had much luck.

I've been able to add the WSDL file(*[CompanyService.wsdl](https://docs.dnb.com/static/doc-uploads/direct/2.0/en-US/company/5.0/CompanyService.zip)*) supplied on their website as a service reference, I don't see clear triggers to request the information and/or where to add username/password for request.

```
MatchRequest mreq = new MatchRequest();
MatchRequestDetail mrd = new MatchRequestDetail();
InquiryDetail ideta = new InquiryDetail();
ideta.DUNSNumber = "804735132";
mrd.InquiryDetail = ideta;
MatchSpecification mspec = new MatchSpecification();
mspec.MatchTypeText = MatchModeEnum.Basic;
mrd.MatchSpecification = mspec;
mreq.MatchRequestDetail = mrd;
```

Any Guidance in this regard would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your generated client should have a Match operation that takes a MatchRequest and gives you back a MatchResponse based on what I'm seeing in the WSDL

```
<wsdl:operation name="Match">
    <wsdl:input message="tns:MatchRequest"/>
    <wsdl:output message="tns:MatchResponse"/>
    <wsdl:fault name="TransactionFault" message="tns:TransactionFault"/>
</wsdl:operation>
```

For example if you generated a service reference with the namespace ServiceReference1 from Visual Studio you should have a class `ServiceReference1.CompanyClient` that you would use like so:

```
ServiceReference1.CompanyClient client = new ServiceReference1.CompanyClient();
MatchResponse mrsp = client.Match(mreq);
```

You can setup the security configuration for the username and password in code or in your app.config

Comment: Thank you very much, I tried suggestion and "Your user credentials are invalid. Please contact your D&B Representative or your local Customer Service Center." so just gotta sort out the App.config

Comment: Thank you @SpaceghostAli for your help. Successfully response finally ` BindingElementCollection elements = client.Endpoint.Binding.CreateBindingElements();
                elements.Find<SecurityBindingElement>().IncludeTimestamp = false;
                client.Endpoint.Binding = new CustomBinding(elements);` I needed to add the above code and edit the app.config